# Change node name

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i have this code from visp_auto_tracker, i want to change the name of the node

```
<!-- -*- xml -*-
     This tutorial relies on a live video sequence acquired with an 
     usb camera in front of a QR code planar target. The model 
     corresponding to this target is given into the models directory 
     of this package.
     Camera parameters are set as rosparam parameters. They need to be changed
     to be the one of your camera.
     See http://www.ros.org/wiki/visp_auto_tracker for more information.
  -->
<launch>
<!-- camera transforms -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" 
        name="jeroen_cam_tf" args="0 0 1.0 -1.570796 0 -1.570796 /map /jeroen_camera 100"/>
    
    
  <!-- Launch the tracking node -->
  <node pkg="visp_auto_tracker" type="visp_auto_tracker" name="visp_auto_tracker" output="screen">
    <param name="model_path" value="$(find visp_auto_tracker)/models" />
    <param name="model_name" value="pattern" />
    <param name="debug_display" value="True" />
          
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to="/usb_cam/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Launch the usb camera acquisition node left -->

  <node pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" name="usb_cam" output="screen">      
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />      
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <!-- rename the camera name topic into /camera/image_raw to match the one in visp_auto_tracker/models/calibration.ini file --> 
    <param name="camera_name" value="/camera/image_raw" />
    <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://visp_auto_tracker/models/calibration.ini" type="string" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

What i want is to change this line:

```
 <node pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" name="usb_cam" output="screen">
```

Into this:

```
 <node pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" name="usb_cam1" output="screen">
```

But the launch file won't work after that change..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279862/change-node-name/) by [Jeroenvdk](https://answers.ros.org/users/32643/jeroenvdk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-15**:
Please always clarify what it is that you observe when something "won't work after that change".

We can't guess what you see, so that makes it very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch file most likely works fine, but you have to make sure that all the other nodes can still subscribe to the topics they need.

This line for instance:

```
<remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to="/usb_cam/camera_info"/>
```

remaps to a `/usb_cam` namespace, which should probably correspond to the name of the `usb_cam` node.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3